# Unity/C# - Sorting list of classes by outside variable

Tags: c#, list, sorting, unity-game-engine

I want to sort my players inventory by an outside value, but my setup is as such:

```
List<ItemHolder> inventory;

class ItemHolder() { int itemID, int itemQuantity }
```

Then for my item database I have:

```
List<Item> itemDB;

class Item() { string itemName, int itemValue } // along with other stuff
```

The `inventory` is made up of any amount of `ItemHolder` classes, and my `itemDB` list made up of possibly hundreds of `Item` ones

I need to sort my `inventory` by comparing with an outside factor (`itemDB[itemID].value`), but after googling I still have no idea how to do this kind of thing. I've seen the Sort() and Linq OrderBy() pop up but as of yet cannot find any applicable to using outside variables.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Is ItemId in fact an index in your List? Do you use it that way because you want to associate a value (itemId) with item itself? Than it would be much easier to use a ```Dictionary<int, Item>``` and then use all those Linq queries you found on it. Or just add the Id field in ```Item``` class.

Comment: You can use outside variables in OrderBy.  eg. `myCollection.OrderBy(item => db[item.id].value)`